# MySQL request working but not on Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm having a problem with MySQL on Wordpress. My code is working fine on local with wamp but when I tried it on Wordpress (still on local) I'm having this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\twentythirteen\check_feedback.php on line 43
```

Here's the code:

```
try {
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=wordpress', 'root', '');
} 
catch(Exception $e) {
    die('Erreur : ' .$e->getMessage());
}

$repGood = $bdd->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM feedback WHERE avis = \'Good\' AND url = \'' . $donnees['url'] . '\'');

while ($isGood = $repGood->fetch()) {
    echo "<br/>".$isGood[0];
}
```

Any idea why it suddenly stopped working with wordpress?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This code saddens me.

Comment: Thank you very much for your constructive answer sir.

Comment: Is this cut`n`pasted or do you really have a `<?php` starting tag in the middle of your script?

Comment: what's this <?php   ????

Comment: this is not the way to interact to database in the wordpress, read documentation

Comment: Sorry it's a mistake when I pasted it^^ It's not in the original code.

Answer (score 0):

As of this documentation, there is no call of `fetch` needed to get the response of your query: http://php.net/manual/de/pdo.query.php.

If you are creating a Wordpress Plugin, you should consider using the provided classes: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb